# Am trying to make my materialize carousel a video instead of image

Tags: javascript, html, css

Am trying to make my materialize carousel a video instead of image, i put the video in a HTML5 video tag, it act normal on mobile and tablet view but the video height is cut in half when it comes to desktop view

```
<div class="carousel carousel-slider">
<a class="carousel-item" href="">
    <video class="" preload="true" autoplay="autoplay" loop="loop" muted
        poster="{%static 'sky_squad_home_app/img/sky_squad_video.jpg'%}">
        <source src="{%static 'sky_squad_home_app/video/sky_squad_video.mp4'%}" type="video/mp4">
        <source src="{%static 'sky_squad_home_app/video/sky_squad_video.webm'%}" type="video/webm">
    </video>
</a>
</div>
<script>
const carouselobj = document.querySelector('.carousel');
M.Carousel.init(carouselobj, {
    fullWidth: true,
    indicators: true
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try 2 things:

split the `<source>` tag that appears one after the other to 2 `carousel-item`s
 and add `style="height: 100%"`:

```
<div class="carousel carousel-slider">
    <a class="carousel-item" href="">
        <video style="height: 100%" preload="true" autoplay="autoplay" loop="loop" muted
            poster="{%static 'sky_squad_home_app/img/sky_squad_video.jpg'%}">
            <source src="{%static 'sky_squad_home_app/video/sky_squad_video.webm'%}" type="video/webm">
        </video>
    </a>
</div>
<div class="carousel carousel-slider">
    <a class="carousel-item" href="">
        <video style="height: 100%" preload="true" autoplay="autoplay" loop="loop" muted
            poster="{%static 'sky_squad_home_app/img/sky_squad_video.jpg'%}">
            <source src="{%static 'sky_squad_home_app/video/sky_squad_video.webm'%}" type="video/webm">
        </video>
    </a>
</div>
<script>
    const carouselobj = document.querySelector('.carousel');
    M.Carousel.init(carouselobj, {
        fullWidth: true,
        indicators: true
    });
</script>
```

Comment: I did what you asked me to , it worked for the full height, but not full width anymore and not responsive as well

Comment: I will be happy to help you if you can share a stackblitz or jsfiddle link :)